# How do I enable Hibernate auto ddl table creation?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.5

I recently switched from Ebean to Hibernate and I want to enable Hibernate table auto-geration.

When I used Ebean, it was quite simple, I just activated the evolutions and Ebean created all my database schemas.

How I can do that with Hibernate?

Comment: JPA providers have a set of standard properties to generate schema with. They work with any JPA 2.1 provider, and docs for your provider ought to contain info about `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action`

Comment: @NeilStockton How can I set the path to the model folder?

Comment: no idea what you're talking about. What "model" folder? JPA requires a persistence.xml that defines your persistence classes

Comment: @NeilStockton app/models

Comment: That's nothing to do with JPA, as said it has persistence.xml. Schema is generated for all classes defined / reachable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**  which can Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

So the list of possible options are,

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.